# ObjectPath: trouble with "in" operator

Tags: python, objectpath

I am learning [ObjectPath](http://objectpath.org/reference.html) for python and have found out, e.g., how to do an exact match on an attribute:

```
>>> import objectpath
>>>
>>> tree = objectpath.Tree({'doc': {'title': 'Purple is Best Color'}})
>>>
>>> tree.execute('$..*[@.title is "Purple is Best Color"]').next()
{'title': 'Purple is Best Color'}
```

This makes sense to me; I want to start from the root (`$`) and recursively (`..`) find all (`*`) items (`@`) for which title == "Purple is Best Color". And it works!

But then I try something similar with the `in` operator:

```
>>> tree.execute('$..*["Purple" in @.title]').next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Huh? Seemed like a natural way to tweak the condition, but it's not quite right.

In the manual, I read that `in` *checks if the result of the left side of expression is in array, object or string*, and that *in objects, keys are matched.* (maybe that's my issue, but not sure quite what it means here). I think that my current `@` is indeed a string...?

Considering the above, what could I be missing here?

Comment: Hi, the quickest option to get help/answer on ObjectPath is through https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath/issues or via Twitter @ adriankal or @ objectpath. You would get an answer in couple of hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interestingly enough, explicitly converting `Purple` to string works:

```
$..*[str("Purple") in @.title]
```

Created an issue at `ObjectPath` issue tracker:

- [in operator confusing behavior](https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath/issues/41)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It hugely helped me in resolving this issue. Turned out I've left some legacy code that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Was a bug. It's fixed now. The fix is available through github (git clone https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath.git).